# Read content of a specific address from flash memory STM32F1

Tags: c, microcontroller

I need to read the content of a specific address from the FLASH memory of a STM32F1 microcontroller. Each address contains 32 bits, so I would like to know if I can do the following:

```
uint32_t addr = 0X0801F000;
read_value = (*((uint32*)(addr)));
```

or should I do something like this:

```
uint32_t addr = 0X0801F000;
read_value = *(unsigned char *)addr;  // this in a loop since char is 8 bits?
```

Comment: Why not `uint32_t *addr = 0X0801F000; read_value = *addr;`  Notice that you missed the star in the declaration of addr.

Comment: Right, thanks for the correction, actually I forgot in the read_value like it is in the second one. So, basically I can read 32 bits at once?

Comment: Sure.  If the pointer is a `uint32_t *addr` then accessing `*addr` will give you a 32 bit number.

Comment: If you want the compiler to not optimize away the actual reading and writing you should declare addr as `volatile uint32_t *addr` (volatile tells the compiler that it MUST read and write to the memory and it can't optimize it away even if it knows what is in the memory location.)

Comment: Very true, I forgot about volatile. So to summarize, in order to read different values each time I can simply do: `read_value = (*((volatile uint32_t*)(0x0801F000)));`?

Comment: That looks right to me.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah You should post an answer instead of many comments. :)

Comment: @BenceKaulics  I find it is always good to make sure the OP agrees that you have the right answer first.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Good point. Thanks for posting the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be written it like this (but see below for a beeter idea):

```
uint32_t *addr = 0X0801F000;
uint32_t read_value = *addr;
```

If you cast `addr` as an `unsigned char *` like you do in your second example, then, when you dereference the unsigned char pointer, you get an unsigned char:

```
uint32_t* addr = 0X0801F000;
unsigned char read_value = *(unsigned char *)addr;
```

So that's not what you want because then you only read one character.  Then, there is one other thing you should remember, you need `volatile` if you want the compiler to read the memory address every single time you dereference the pointer.  Otherwise, the compile could skip that if it already knows that the value is.  Then you would have to write it like this:

```
volatile uint32_t *addr = 0X0801F000;
uint32_t read_value = *addr;
```

Or if you put it all on one line (like you did in your comment):

```
uint32_t read_value = (*((volatile uint32_t*)(0x0801F000)));
```